# Popup control on Datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid, popup

I'm having two issues here. I have a DataGrid populated with some items. What I want to happen is display a Popup control under the DataGrid selected row. Here's what I have:

```
<Grid>
    <DataGrid CanUserReorderColumns="False" 
              CanUserSortColumns="False" 
              HeadersVisibility="None" 
              AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
              VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
              ItemsSource="{Binding ItemCollection}" 
              SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Width="*" Binding="{Binding Path=Key}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Width="*" Binding="{Binding Path=Value}" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>

    <Popup PopupAnimation="Scroll" Placement="Bottom" AllowsTransparency="True" IsOpen="{Binding PopupVisible}" Margin="0" StaysOpen="True" >
        <local:PopupControl />
    </Popup>
</Grid>
```

I set the IsOpen property in my ViewModel when SelectedItem is changed like so:

```
PopupVisible = true;
```

With this code I am able to show the popover.

**First Issue:** With StaysOpen = "True" the popup will not move when the window is moved. The way I handle this with a Button control is to change StaysOpen to "False" so that the popup is dismissed when clicking somewhere else in the window. When I do this with the DataGrid control the popup doesn't show at all when SelectedItem is changed. Why is this?

**Second Issue:** How do I get the popup to display under the selected row?

Comment: In your popup xaml block, change Placement="MousePoint" and then, IsOpen="True" in the cell click event of datagrid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution worked for me:

**First Issue:**
When you open your popup initially, save the window co-ordinates.

```
Point coordinate = mainWindow.PointFromScreen(new Point(0,0));
xSavedWindowPos = coordinate.X;
ySavedWindowPos = coordinate.Y;
```

In your LocationChanged event handler of mainWindow: Set the popup Offsets and save the new Window Position.

```
Point currentPos = (sender as Window).PointFromScreen(new Point(0,0));
yourPopup.HorizontalOffset += (xSavedWindowPos - currentPos.X);
yourPopup.VerticalOffset += (ySavedWindowPos - currentPos.Y);
xSavedWindowPos = currentPos.X;
ySavedWindowPos = currentPos.Y;
```

**Second Issue**: Open the popup in the "CellMouseClick" event handler of the datagrid. You can set StaysOpen too.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a CellMouseClick event handler in the DataGrid control. Is there some library or something that adds this? Also, is there any way to do this using MVVM?

Comment: DataGrid control orginally was not there in WPF. So, in WPF application I used WinForms datagrid control. This has got CellMouseClick Event. May be similar event may be available. How about your first Issue ?

Comment: Check with Mouse Left button down event in DataGrid Control. If you done with that 'Placement' property of popup (Placement="MousePoint") you can popup on that point. Else you need to check with other related events.

Comment: You solution to the first issue does work. For the second issue I was able to get it working using the MouseLeftButtonUp event handler. The problem is that I'm looking for an MVVM solution to this. Do you have any ideas on how I could do that?

Comment: So I ended up going a different route and used a custom ContextMenu on a ListView to get what I was after. Your solutions did answer my questions so I accepted it. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Good if you could able to come out with answer. I also did through ContextMenu option but directly on Datagrid, ofcourse WinForms Datagrid hosted on WPF. CurrentCell/Index option might be the possibility @ your end.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, Are you using Ajax for the popout control?

This is how i do it using ajax

At TOP of page Under normal code

```
        <cc1:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalPopupExtender_View" runat="server"
                            PopupControlID="popView" CancelControlID="cmdViewClose" TargetControlID="hidForModel" PopupDragHandleControlID="Panel1"
                            DropShadow="true" BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground" RepositionMode="None"></cc1:ModalPopupExtender>
```

The Hidden Field is what sets the position of the Popout on the page

For the button click you can use
ModalPopupExtender_View.Show();
in the code behind